# Error in legend(1, 1, xjust = 1, yjust = 1, legend = levels(relatedness$RT), : 'legend' is of length 0

Tags: r, plot, legend

I'm trying to generate a plot using the following code, but keep getting this error:

```
pdf("rel.pdf")
relatedness = read.table("pihat.gen", header=T)
par(pch=16, cex=1)
with(relatedness,plot(Z0,Z1, xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(0,1), type="n"))
with(subset(relatedness,RT=="PO") , points(Z0,Z1,col=4))
with(subset(relatedness,RT=="UN") , points(Z0,Z1,col=3))
legend(1,1, xjust=1, yjust=1, legend=levels(relatedness$RT), pch=16, col=c(4,3))
```

Error: Error in legend(1, 1, xjust = 1, yjust = 1, legend = levels(relatedness$RT),  :    'legend' is of length 0

Comment: You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: When you type the command `levels(relatedness$RT)`, what do you get? Your command assumes that `RT` is a factor. Is it? If not, `legend=c("PO", "UN")` might be what you want.